# Want to Manage Google cloud bucket from J2SE application

Tags: java, swing, google-app-engine, awt, google-cloud-storage

I am developing a J2SE application where I want to access Google cloud bucket storage. But My problem is:

1. I found web solution for this problem
2. I don't know how to access from Desktop based swing application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to access a Google Cloud Storage bucket from the desktop.

First, we need to figure out how to handle authentication. If your objects are available to everyone, we can skip this step. If you need the users of your application to authenticate themselves with their own Google accounts, that's available. Alternately, you can create a special account called a "service account" that represents your application and distribute the credentials for that account with your application.

Google Cloud Storage has two APIs outside of App Engine. One of them, the JSON API, has a Java client, so let's use that one. You can see instructions here: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/api-lib/java.

There are two examples you may want to look at. [storage-cmdline-sample](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/storage-cmdline-sample/instructions.html) is a sample that asks users to authenticate themselves, and [storage-serviceaccount-cmdline-sample](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/storage-serviceaccount-cmdline-sample/instructions.html) is a sample that uses an application service account.

You'll need the Google API Java client. It's available via Maven, or you can just [download it](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/downloads/list). The client is interesting because it can be used to access many different Google APIs, including Google Cloud Storage but also many other things, like Google Translate or Google Compute Engine.

If the examples aren't enough, you can see the full documentation on Google Cloud Storage's JSON API here: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/